# dynamic UIButton lldb crash

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uibutton

So i'm creating buttons and filling my view with them:

```
    -(void) generateAnimalsForView:(UIView *)view withAnimals:(NSString *)animalName animalCount:(int)count
{
    animalsView = view;

    //get size of main view
    int viewWidth = view.frame.size.width - animalWidth;
    int viewHeight = view.frame.size.height - animalHeight;

    if (count > maxCountOfAnimals)
        count = maxCountOfAnimals;

    if (count > 0){

        UIButton *initialView = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(animalWidth+arc4random() % (int)viewWidth, animalHeight+arc4random() % (int)viewHeight, animalWidth, animalHeight)];
        [initialView setTag:100];
        [initialView addTarget:self action:@selector(setAnimationForRunning:) forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [initialView setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"animal"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [view addSubview:initialView];

        int numViews = 0;

        while (numViews < count-1) {
            BOOL goodView = YES;
            UIButton *candidateView = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(arc4random() % (int)viewWidth, arc4random() % (int)viewHeight, animalWidth, animalHeight)];
            [candidateView setTag:100+numViews+1];
            [candidateView addTarget:self action:@selector(setAnimationForRunning:) forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)UIControlEventTouchDown];
            [candidateView setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"animal"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            for (UIButton *placedView in view.subviews) {
                if (CGRectIntersectsRect(CGRectInset(candidateView.frame, 5+arc4random()%5, 5+arc4random()%5), placedView.frame)) {
                    goodView = NO;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (goodView) {
                [view addSubview:candidateView];
                numViews += 1;
            }}
        }
}
```

My problem is that i'm getting `lldb` crash every time i press button and i have no idea why this is happening... my `setAnimationForRunning` method just have `NSLog` in it, and it doesn't even firing this method.

---

**EDIT:**

crash message:

```
(lldb)
```

And it stops on `main` method.

My  `setAnimationForRunning` method:

```
- (IBAction)setAnimationForRunning:(UIButton *)sender{ 
    NSLog(@"set animation for running");
}
```

---

**EDIT 2:**

So the thing is that i have this method in my model class, and when i'm trying to create buttons with action using this class from my VC it's crashing with error lldb.

```
AnimalsModel *animalsModel = [[AnimalsModel alloc] init];//model for math and stuff
[animalsModel generateAnimalsForView:animalsView withAnimals:@"animal" animalCount:(int)fResultWeight];
```

but when i'm creating same method in my VC and using it:

```
[self generateAnimalsForView:animalsView withAnimals:@"animal" animalCount:(int)fResultWeight];
```

buttons is created and everything works perfectly. Can please some one explain to me why this is happening? Thanks

Comment: Add the EXACT and FULL error message to your question. And surely it crashes on a specific line?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` for the button?

Comment: Nah, just testing how it will work with `UIControlEventTouchDown`

Comment: enable Exception Break point for all and see where exactly your app crash.